# how to drop rows in dataframe if it contains duplicate values

Tags: pandas

How can I drop duplicate rows in DataFrame?

My initial DataFrame is like this:

```
S.No    Column1 Column2
7       A       B
2       D       F
5       C       H
9       A       J
1       T       G
4       Z       A
10      S       Y
3       G       V
10      R       Y
8       T       X
```

Here, S.No 10 is repeated two times and I'd like to delete it in one iteration:

```
n = 2

while n <= len(df):

    df1 = df.tail(n)

    cond = df.Column1 < df.Column2

    df.loc[cond, ['Column1', 'Column2']] = df.loc[cond, ['Column2', 'Column1']].values


    print(df1)

    df2 = df1.to_dict("records")

    db_cm.insert_one({"data": df2, "time stamp": datetime.now()})

    df.drop(df1.index ,inplace=True)

    n = n + 1

else:
    print(df.tail(n))
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='S.No', keep="first")
```

You can specify to keep the first row for example.